# @NotNull, @Nonnull etc. all don't work in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have tried annotating a field with

- org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull
- org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
- javax.annotation.Nonnull

And in all cases, assigning a null to it generates no complaints from IntelliJ 2016.2.

```
public class GreetingController {
    @NotNull Integer x = 3;
    public void foo() { x = null; }
}
```

That all compiles fine according to IntelliJ.

[This page from IntelliJ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/03/detecting-probably-npes/) specifically states that "IntelliJ IDEA highlights the problems “on-the-fly”, so you can see the inspection results right in the editor." I have even copied the example code (`public class TestNullable`) into my editor and it produces no errors.

[This other page from IntelliJ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/more-flexible-and-configurable-nullublenotnull-annotations/) states you can change the annotations it responds to. So I chose javax.annotation.Nonnull and made sure that was the one I was using in my code, still no luck.

To be clear, what I'm hoping for, and what I understand should be provided, is that the editor window / compiler alerts me to the problem (I am not looking for a runtime check, NullPointerException already works fine at runtime.)

In case it didn't work in real time, I tried "Rebuild Project".

I'm sure this must work, what am I doing wrong?

I have uploaded an example of this not working here: [ZIP download](https://www.databasesandlife.com/not-null.zip).

Comment: Do you have [this inspection](http://i.imgur.com/N2BYJFX.png) enabled? Can you show the screenshot of the editor (full IDE window)? I [can't reproduce the problem](http://i.imgur.com/BO91a3a.png). Could be a misconfigured project, like Java file outside of the source root, inspections disabled, power save mode enabled, etc. Sharing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have uploaded an example here: https://www.databasesandlife.com/not-null.zip I am new to IntelliJ (started today), please let me know if what I've exported isn't the right stuff to allow you to import the project. I have a single source file which uses `javax.annotation.Nonnull`. As you can see from the screenshots, the inspection is enabled, powersave is not enabled, yet there is no warning/error shown. (Also with `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` it's the same.)

Comment: As I can see from your screenshots and the sample project, IntelliJ IDEA [does show you the warnings](http://i.imgur.com/484n68P.png). Note that these warnings are shown by the code inspections which are running on the fly and will be displayed in the editor or in the Analyze | Inspect Code results. These warnings will not be displayed by the compiler.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you !! The colour scheme was just too subtle, I just didn't see it. I am used to Eclipse having the red wavy underline. I have spent most of the afternoon trying to get this to work :) If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see from your screenshots and the sample project, IntelliJ IDEA [does show you the warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rhi6.png). Note that these warnings are shown by the code inspections which are running on the fly and will be displayed in the editor or in the Analyze | Inspect Code results. These warnings will not be displayed by the compiler.

[image: warning]

Note that you can configure the warnings highlighting if needed (for example add the underwave effect):

[image: warning]

You can also change the severity of the inspection (like to Error):

[image: severity]

You may also want to vote for this feature request:

- [IDEA-78625](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625) Provide inspection severity level that will work like validation and abort compilation

As a bonus, pay attention to the `javax.annotation.Nullable` annotation, it may be not what you think it's for, see [this comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jsr-305/mU-HqM4jwtk/Hoq1uPrykHMJ) and the [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/javax/annotation/Nullable.html). For some years IntelliJ IDEA has incorrectly suggested to use this annotation, while the correct one for such cases would be `javax.annotation.CheckForNull`:

> This annotation is useful mostly for overriding a `Nonnull` annotation.
>   Static analysis tools should generally treat the annotated items as
>   though they had no annotation, unless they are configured to minimize
>   false negatives. Use `CheckForNull` to indicate that the element value
>   should always be checked for a null value.

Answer (score 4):

1. "Settings" > "Inspections" > "Probable Bugs" > "Constant conditions & exceptions"
2. Tick the first option: "Suggest @NotNull annotation for methods that possibly return null and report nullable values passed to non-annotated parameters.
3. Click "Configure Annotations". By default, Intellij will use their own annotations from `org.jetbrains.annotation`. I was using the more general (my own opinion) annotations from `javax.annotation`.
4. I set Nullable to: `javax.annotation.Nullable`
5. I set NotNUll to : `javax.annotation.NotNull`
6. **In order to set these new options, you must click them, then click the tiny checkmark button to the right to set it.** Selecting the `javax.annotation` annotations then hitting "OK" will NOT lock in the new settings, you must use the checkbox button.

After successfully specifying `javax.annotation.Nullable` and `javax.annotation.NotNull`, the code correctly highlighted null problems.

Answer (score 0):

The *best* that this can do is offer up warnings.  It will not stop compilation from happening, since the annotations do not prohibit or preclude code compilation from taking place.

Be sure that you have the appropriate inspections enabled in your IDE, and be sure that you remain aware of what parameters you're passing into your method.  The IDE can at best warn you, but it can't really stop you.

Alternatively, introduce a unit test to fail if that method receives a null parameter, and rely on that to ensure that you're not breaking code or expectations.